# In standard SQL is lead with offset -1 same as lag with offset +1?

Tags: sql, window-functions

SQL provides the two window functions `lead` and `lag` to get the nth previous respectively next value based on given conditions. Now, given that both functions take an optional offset value, is it correct that `lead(col1, -n) === lag(col1, n)` and the other way round? Or for that matter `lead(col1, -n) over(order by col2 asc) === lead(col1, +n) over(order by col2 desc)`.

This seems to obvious conclusion but the fact that a) this is not explicitly mentioned in any documentation and that b) both functions do exists whereas with above equivalence only one function would be necessary without loss of functionality, leads me to believe that I might be missing something here.

So does the equivalence hold and if not, what's a scenario where `lead` and `lag` will differ?

Comment: @jpw . . . Not really.  You can just change the ordering in `order by` clause.

Comment: Well SQL isn't know for brevity or to always offer a single way of doing things. A `right join` isn't necessary either, it can be done with a `left join` as well. However the `offset` in the `lag()` or `lead()` functions is defined as an "unsigned integer" in the SQL standard. So according to the standard `lag(col1, -1)` isn't even valid.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Yeah that is something else I was assuming that I should have mentioned in the question, but for instance the Oracle documentation doesn't mention any restriction on the offset whereas MS T-SQL for instance explicitly mentions positive integer. Where would I find the official ANSI SQL definition for this?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Yes another duality there. As I said, it seems to me like having both those methods is redundant. Hence I was wondering if there is any difference, or if it is, as a_horse_with_no_name pointed out, it's like left and right outer join.

Comment: in practice though, there is seldomly a need for the pure-orthohonal before  <--> after case. (Compare it, for instance, to the boolean-XOR)